# Setting validation rules on array input

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, validation, if-statement, error-handling

```
<input type='text' name='names[]'/>


$validation = array(array('field' => names, 'label'=> , 'rules'=>'required'););
```

Question.

How would i be able to validate the array values in names 1 by 1?

Im very confused to the point im catching myself going back n forth with how i can do this.

`'field' => 'names[$i]'` - im sure this is wrong.

I am adding recipes to my DB. Simple Add CRUD function. But i want it to be a smart one. So i put up alot of ifs to catch any error to be able to record them and to show the users why.

```
function recipe_add(){
    if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST)){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('recipename','Recipe Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('recipedescription','Recipe Description', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('recipeinstruction','Recipe Instruction','trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){$this->load->view('Admin/insert_recipe2');}else{
        $ingredients = array();
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        if($_POST['ingredient'][$i]!=null AND ! preg_match('#[0-9]#',$_POST['ingredient'][$i]) AND is_numeric($_POST['quantity'][$i])){
        $ingredients[$_POST['ingredient'][$i]] = $_POST['quantity'][$i].'-'.$_POST['measurement'][$i];}
        } if(count($ingredients)<1){$this->load->view('Admin/insert_recipe2');}
        else{
        $config['upload_path'] = './Admin_uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '270';
        $config['max_height']  = '280';     
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);        
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('recipeimage')){
        $this->load->view('Admin/insert_recipe2');
        }else{
        $recipetoInsert['image'] = $this->upload->data();
        $recipetoInsert['name'] = $_POST['recipename'];
        $recipetoInsert['description'] = $_POST['recipedescription'];
        $recipetoInsert['instruction'] = $_POST['recipeinstruction'];
        print_r($recipetoInsert);
        /**if(!$this->KGAdminCRUDModel->insert_recipe($recipetoInsert)){
        $data['Insertion_Error'] = 'Adding recipe to Database Failed.';
        $data['Insertion_Error_Reason'] = '';
        $this->load->view('Admin/insert_recipe2',$data);}
        else{
        $data['Success_Message'] = 'Recipe Added successfully to the Database';
        $data['Success_Data_Details'] = $recipetoInsert;
        $this->load->view('Admin/insert_recipe2',$data);}**/
        }
        }
        }
        else{ $this->load->view('Admin/insert_recipe2');}}
```

Im having trouble with the ifs getting tangled. im having if else errors unexpected.

Comment: just use `names[]` CI will be the one to track Where it came from.

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('names[]','','');

That is it then?... Okay assuming CI will handle the tracking. ill try